# Why android Recyclerview automatically update without adapter notifyDataSetChanged() method called? when data is coming from web socket background

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am showing list of data by recyclerview. so when data is comming from web socket then adding new items in existing list so my recyclerview update automatically. i am not explicitly calling notifyDataSetChanged() so how it's updating?.

If i will adding items by any button click event so it require to call notifyDataSetChanged() method then data will update but when data is coming web socket so it not require to call notifyDataSetChanged() method and data will update automatically.

Comment: `adding new items in existing list so my recyclerview update automatically` Sorry, just dont believe that.

Comment: i also do not believe that but practically it's working @blackapps

Comment: If you only append your list it will work if as long as your list is already large enough to be scrollable and you're not on the bottom of it. However you cannot rely on this behavior (since it's just a quirk of linearlayoutmanager implementation) and you should be notifying your list changes - preferably with a diff rather than datasetchanged.